# Django Choices Tuple

Tags: python, django

I'm not sure if this has been answered before but here goes

I have this code

```
ITEM = [
    ('Fruits', (
            ('a', 'Apple'),
            ('g', 'Grape'),
            ('m', 'Mango')
        )
    ),

    ('Vegetables', (
            ('b', 'Broccoli'),
            ('p', 'Peanut'),
            ('t', 'Tomato')
        )
    ),
]
```

With that I'm trying to access the human-readable version of the tuples in my model like this

```
item = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ITEM)
```

However when I submitted this field from django admin page, it submits let's say 'a' instead of 'Apple'

How can I make sure that I submitted 'Apple' into the database to be displayed in HTML later on?

Comment: Why not make Item into a model with a `name` and `category` field?

Comment: @KentShikama because you don't necessarily want to use a related model for choices values - either because it doesn't need to be admin-editable or it actually needs to NOT be admin-editable (think about code relying on this value for doing different things... you certainly don't want to mix hardcoded and editable things here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render the value with [**`get_fieldname_display`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display). As is specified in the documentation:

> For every field that has choices set, the object will have a `get_FOO_display()` method, where `FOO` is the name of the field. This method returns the **"human-readable" value** of the field.

So if you later in your template want to render the human-readable value for the `item` field, you render this with:

```
{{ my_object.get_item_display }}
```

Comment: turns out i did not need the bracket to make it work on the view. Thanks